# Confusion with why fs can be run as a function containing only array

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and came across a code that a bit confused me which is:

```
function buildFunctions() {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr.push(
      function () {
        console.log(i); 
      }
    )
  }

  return arr;
}

var fs = buildFunctions();

fs[0]();
fs[1]();
fs[2]();
```

The question is when we equalize fs to buildFunctions() then buildFunctions is run and returns an array. So, fs only has array inside then how is it possible that fs can be run as a function since it only has array inside like so

```
fs[0]();
fs[1]();
fs[2]();
```

Again, fs has an array inside then how can we run fs as a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs` is an array. Inside that array are three elements. Each of the three elements is a function. Those functions were created by this code:

```
function () {
  console.log(i); 
}
```

... and were inserted into the array with this code:

```
arr.push(
  function () {
    console.log(i); 
  }
)
```

so accessing `fs[0]` returns the 0th element of the array, which is a function, and thus `fs[0]()` is the code necessary to call that function.